# Getting caching working with Django

Tags: django, django-cache, django-caching

We are trying to implement caching in Django. We have tried memcache, file system caching and local memory caching. No mater what it just isn't working -- a timestamp we put on the template to test caching is always updating so we know it's not working.

Here are relevant portions of code.

```
CACHES = {
   'default': {
       'BACKEND': 'django.core.cache.backends.filebased.FileBasedCache',
       'LOCATION': 'c:/tmp',
   }
}

CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_ALIAS = "default"
CACHE_MIDDLEWARE_SECONDS = 600

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = [
   "django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware",
    ... OTHER ONES ...
   "django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware",
    ]
```

VIEWS.PY

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page

@cache_page(60 * 10)
def profiles(request, template_name="profiles/profiles.html", extra_context=None):
   ...
```